# why parameters.yml loses changes when I update dependencies using Composer?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When I run: `php composer.phar update` after adding a line to  `require-dev` in `composer.json`, I observe that `parameters.yml` loses all the changes I made from it initial state (when Symfony2 standard edition is first installed). What are reasons behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your parameters in `parameters.yml.dist`, because `parameters.yml` is regenerated from the `.dist` file after each composer update.

The `.dist` file can be added to your VCS of choice and when someone pulls the changes, Symfony will check if there are any differences between `parameters.yml.dist` and local `parameters.yml`, will ask the user to provide a value for any new parameter and it will add it to local `parameters.yml` file.

Comment: When you say "Symfony will check if there are any differences between parameters.yml.dist and local parameters.yml", you mean during 'composer update/install'. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The indeed of this behaviour is because the script want to **remove outdated params**.

If you need to keep outdated params you can use keep-outdated param in the configuration:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "keep-outdated": true
        }
    }
}
```

More info in the bundle's doc [here](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler#keeping-outdated-parameters)

Comment: Hi @whitelettersinblankpapers you are welcome! i post this only for completation of the arguments